# SQL Developer - Signed in as DBA but priveleges are removed

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

These two privileges don't get granted to the DBA:

- SYSDBA
- SYSOPER

SQL and GUI attempts to grant these privileges return successful messages, but they remain revoked. While signed in as SYS:

[Signing in as SYS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlIzU.png)

[Bookshop_DBA privileges appear as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILl24.png)

[Granting with GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6lW2.png)

[Granting with SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwRy7.png)

[Result for both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gK8X.png)

Messages are returned to say that granting is successful but no changes are made.

Comment: What two privileges?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is normal, and because those [aren't standard privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/getting-started-with-database-administration.html#GUID-5F1E393E-97B8-43BC-BD68-3595251A6F7C). They don't appear in `dba_sys_privs` either. Why do you think this is causing you an issue, if you're already successfully connected as SYSDBA?

Comment: So which user are you editing there?

Comment: This is the DBA I'm editing. I will tick all these boxes and hit apply. I get a message: "Successfully processed SQL command" but the changes aren't applied.

Comment: what does 'select * from V$PWFILE_USERS' show?

Comment: you're using a screen in sqldev to confirm it works...but the db has already TOLD you it works. what you haven't done is try to login as your user AS SYSDBA. Do that. I think you have found a bug where the Edit User dialog doesn't accurately show status of SYSDBA priv.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith The select statement shows that the DBA has SYSDBA and SYSOPER privileges. It may be a bug as you described. I assumed this may be the cause of other issues I am having. As teething issues of learning the software they are likely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show us what you're actually doing.

If you're using the dialog as shown, and getting problems, you should be able to report an any ORA- errors.

For example:

[image]

And you don't have to guess what SQL Developer is actually doing - click on the SQL page of the edit user dialog.

[image]

Before going further, please consider:

1. you should in general NEVER login as SYSDBA - unless you need to actually shut down or alter a database. Don't use it as an all powerful PRIV to get around security/grant issues
2. you should know what you're doing before you grant it to someone, or even use it yourself. Read the docs, then read them again. Otherwise, this is how you do very, very bad things to your database.

Running this code from a non-privileged user:

```
-- SYSTEM PRIVILEGES
GRANT SYSDBA TO "user" ;
GRANT SYSOPER TO "user" ;

Error starting at line : 6 in command -
GRANT SYSDBA TO "user"
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Error starting at line : 7 in command -
GRANT SYSOPER TO "user"
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

So, how do we get around this?

You need to do this for the user who is performing the grants - and you better REALLY trust this user, if you're going to let them do this SYSDBA...

```
GRANT SYSDBA TO "*user*" WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

But, that's NOT ENOUGH.

Per the DOCS:

> Because SYSDBA and SYSOPER are the most powerful database privileges,
>   the WITH ADMIN OPTION is not used in the GRANT statement. That is, the
>   grantee cannot in turn grant the SYSDBA or SYSOPER privilege to
>   another user. Only a user currently connected as SYSDBA can grant or
>   revoke another user's SYSDBA or SYSOPER system privileges. These
>   privileges cannot be granted to roles, because roles are available
>   only after database startup. Do not confuse the SYSDBA and SYSOPER
>   database privileges with operating system roles.

So, in SQL Developer, disconnect.

Change your connection properties:

[image]

Now that you're connected as SYSDBA, you can do...perilous things...like grant that to someone else.

PS - Don't ever GRANT SYS anything to a demo schema like HR. And don't have these demo schemas in production environments, they're only there as learning resources.

Comment: This is useful information for me, thank you. I hope my edit makes more clear the issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the user you are connected with. SYSDBA and SYSOPER privs can only be granted by a SYSDBA user.

Comment: I connect as the SYSDBA to add the privileges but no luck.